# Call routes from js file

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5.1

I am new to laravel, so i don't know how to call a route from a js file.

```
$.post('executeSearch',{keywords: keywords},function(markup){
   console.log('Test2 passed');
   $('#search-results').html(markup);
});
```

I am trying to call a post route named executeSearch and I am using localhost.

Comment: Your JS is fine. Are you getting status codes back? An error? You're probably just not registering the route correctly on the Laravel side of things. As it stands right now, you're not going to get much help since there aren't any details. If you edit the question and provide more info, I'm sure someone could lend a hand here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.post('/executeSearch',{keywords: keywords},function(markup){
   console.log('Test2 passed');
   $('#search-results').html(markup);
});
```

Do you see the beginning slash in the url? You can read here more about it: [What is the purpose of leading slash in HTML URLs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls)

Also make sure you're sending the [csrf token](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection)

Comment: It is giving POST http://localhost:8000/executeSearch 500 (Internal Server Error) error in the console

Comment: edit your post and show us your laravel routes, it should look like: Route::post('executeSearch', ['uses' => 'Controller@action']);

Comment: Route::post('executeSearch',array('uses' => 'SearchController@executeSearch'));

Comment: you have some error in your php, press f12 go to network tab, now fire the ajax, click on the 500 request click on preview tab, what error you getting?

Comment: It is giving an error as TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53. But which file is it referring to?

Comment: so your route is working, and your js code is good, you need to read about csrf protection: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: For now i have disabled the csrf protection in the VerifyCsfrToken.php. But still I am not getting any output for the ajax.

Comment: again in js you need to work with the console, you getting any error? if you put in your controller dd('test') you getting it in console?

Comment: Actually I am getting the results in the console i.e in the network tab. But its not giving in the dropdown format. Do i need to return using json? Now I am using return View::make('searchCompanies')>with('searchCompany',$searchCompany);

Comment: its different question, you need to open a new one if you want help with js

Comment: Can you tell me how to make ajax work in dropdown format using laravel 5.1?

Comment: yes if you need other help with other question you need to open a new question, add as much info as possible

Comment: no problem :) if you can accept my answer as the correct one